# Ionic and angularjs nested steps app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am just learning angularjs and ionic frameworks, And i copied one of the demo and tried to make changes but not sure why its not working.
I am not able to see "speakers profile details" page.

```
- Speakers
--- Speakers lists
----- Speakers profile details
- Schedule
- venue
- sponsors
```

Here is the code pen demo

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJwGBr)

Comment: It would help if you had a profile 'details' page - did you mean 'info'?

Comment: Also since you're using the state-provider you should look at the ui-sref directive https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref - you reference a state rather than url.

Comment: @ChrisMoutray : i want to show speakers bio on that page, I will look at the link you provided, will get back to you soon. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 3 things that contribute to this not working:

1. The speakersinfo template is missing ion-view and ion-content.

Make sure it starts like this:

```
<script id="templates/speakersinfo.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-view view-title="Speakers Info">
    <ion-content>
```

2. The controller names do not match - you reference the controller in the state provider as `speakerInfo` (without 's' on end of speaker) but declared the controller as `speakersinfo` (with 's' on end of speaker).

Make sure the names match (which ever way you decide).

3. You try to access the state `eventmenu.speakers.speakersinfo` using the url `#/event/speakersinfo` but its important to understand how nested states work with the angular-ui/ui-router - the url in the state declaration is **appended** to its inherited state. So here `eventmenu.speakers.speakersinfo` is a child state of `eventmenu.speakers` so the url must be `#/event/speakers/speakersinfo`.
   Or you could change the state name to `eventmenu.speakersinfo` - I tried this and it worked for me.

Personally I think its better to use the `ui-sref` attribute instead of href the url; this way you use the declared state name and there's no confusion.

Also just to mention that you've repeated the template for attendees
    `<script id="templates/attendees.html" type="text/ng-template">`

Comment: third trick worked, still confused why nested state not working...anyways i think i need to real the documentation more carefully, once again. Thanks for the solution though. Here is the link for those who are facing the same problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJwGBr